# Rules do not work in my gitlab-ci, why include file is ignored?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, rules

part of my gitlab-ci.yaml looks like that

```
include:
  # Base templates
  - '/templates.yml'

envsubst:
  image: ${K8S_DEPLOY_IMAGE}
  stage: tests
  rules:
    - <<: *if-commit
      when: on_success
  tags:
   - k8s
  script:
   - envsubst --version
```

in this case *if-commit rule is:

```
.if-commit: &if-commit
  if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
```

this rule exists in my templates.yaml file and "include" contains this file in gitlab-ci as you see

gitlab says "yaml invalid", but if rule (which templates.yaml contains) will be in gitlab-ci, everything goes well and yaml is valid

so, include for some reasons does not work and "include" ignores my rules